# Website redirecting to 404 Error page in IE

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, redirect

I am designing a template website. The website is working fine in all browsers except IE.
When opened in IE, The website is redirecting to a 404 error page.

Site Link:
http://www.fakhrolaemeh.com/index.aspx?pid=1

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
    alert('This is Internet Explorer');
    //Your redirection code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no Image in this URL

http://www.fakhrolaemeh.com/Files/298/105/theme/mainbk.png

Either add image to this folder or remove it in asp page.

Comment: tanks   iam rempve code and img  mainbk.png  the problem in only ie   The problem is not solved  in ie only

Comment: You should try `Trial and Error` method to find the error. Like remove some elements in the page and reload. Do this until it works.

Comment: Problem solved because the file pie remove pie file not show masseg error 404 in ie

Very tnx

Answer (score 1):

```
var navigatorAgent = navigator.userAgent;
if(navigatorAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
    //your redirection code comes here
}
```

OR

```
var browserName = navigator.appName;
if( browserName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    //your redirection code comes here
}
```

**NOTE**: If using JQuery:
The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3, and its functionality may be moved to a team-supported plugin in a future release of jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
    alert('IE');
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: don't browser sniff, feature detect. And do not serve different content just because it is IE. Include all vendor specific prefixes on your CSS instead, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved because the file pie 
remove pie  file not show masseg error 404 in ie

Very tnx

Comment: hi frends When the problem is the format that was designed to monitor widescreen format is not set
  What solution do you propose

Comment: When the problem is the format that was designed to monitor widescreen format is not set
  What solution do you propose
fakhrolaemeh.com/index.aspx?pid=1

Comment: When the problem is the format that was designed to monitor widescreen format is not set
  What solution do you propose
fakhrolaemeh.com/index.aspx?pid=1